# ¿Alguien sabria decirme en que falla mi codigo en java?

Tags: java

Mi código no compila y ya no se que mas hacerle, por eso pregunto si alguien podría decirme en que en mi código

```
public class Computadora{
    
    int discoDuro;
    float velocidadProcesador;
    Computadora peer;
    String sistemaOperativo;
    String nombre;

    public Computadora(String nombreEquipo){
        discoDuro = 640;
        velocidadProcesador = 3.1;
        sistemaOperativo = "Microsoft Windows 7";
        nombre = nombreEquipo;
        String[] memoria = new String[10];      
    }
    
    public void encender(){
        System.out.println(nombre + ": Iniciando Windows...");
        memoria[0] = sistemaOperativo;      
        System.out.println(nombre + ": Bienvenido");
    }
    
    public boolean ejecutar(String programa, int posicion){
        if(posicion != 0){
            memoria[posicion] = programa;
            System.out.println(nombre + ": Ejecutando el programa " + programa);
            return true;
            }
        }
    }
    
    public void recibirDatos(String mensaje){
        System.out.println(peer.nombre + " dice: " + mensaje);
        
    }
    
    public void enviarDatos(){
        peer.recibirDatos("Escribe aquí el dato a enviar");
        return 0;
    }
    
    public void conectar(Computadora c){
        this.peer = c;
        c.peer = this;
        System.out.println(nombre + ": Conectado a " + peer.nombre);
    }
    
    public void desconectar(){
        System.out.println(nombre + ": Desconectado de " + peer.nombre);
        peer.peer = null;
        this.peer = null;
    }
    
    public void apagar(){
        System.out.println("Cerrando sesión...");
        for(int i = 1; i < 11; i++){
            memoria[i] = null;
        }
        System.out.println(nombre + ": Windows se está cerrando");
        memoria[0] = null;
    }
    
    public static void aumentarDiscoDuro(){
        discoDuro = 1000;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Computadora laptop = new Computadora("Laptop");
        laptop.encender();
        laptop.ejecutar("Windows Live Messenger", 1);
        
        Computadora tablet = new Computadora("Tablet");
        tablet.encender();
        tablet.ejecutar("Windows Live Messenger", 1);
        
        laptop.conectar(tablet);    
        laptop.enviarDatos();
        laptop.desconectar();
        
        tablet.apagar();
        laptop.apagar();
    }
}
```

Comment: A la comunidad le sería mas simple si por ejemplo añades el mensaje de error que obtienes

Comment: También realizar el [tour], ya que se resume en: Me da fallos, pegas el código y a esperar que alguien lo realice por mi. Que al final lo has conseguido en vez de darte cuenta que estaba mal construido.

Answer (score 0):

Código con las correcciones enumeradas:

```
public class Computadora{
        
        int discoDuro;
        float velocidadProcesador;
        Computadora peer;
        String sistemaOperativo;
        String nombre;
        //  4. El arreglo memoria debe ser de instancia
        String[] memoria;
        public Computadora(String nombreEquipo){
            discoDuro = 640;
            // 6. El tipo de dato debe ser float
            velocidadProcesador = 3.1f;
            sistemaOperativo = "Microsoft Windows 7";
            nombre = nombreEquipo;
            memoria = new String[10];      
        }
        
        public void encender(){
            System.out.println(nombre + ": Iniciando Windows...");
            memoria[0] = sistemaOperativo;      
            System.out.println(nombre + ": Bienvenido");
        }
        
        public boolean ejecutar(String programa, int posicion){
            if(posicion != 0){
                memoria[posicion] = programa;
                System.out.println(nombre + ": Ejecutando el programa " + programa);
                return true;
                }
           // } 1. La llave está de más
           // 2. Falta el return por defecto
           return false;
        }
        
        public void recibirDatos(String mensaje){
            System.out.println(peer.nombre + " dice: " + mensaje);
            
        }
        
        public void enviarDatos(){
            peer.recibirDatos("Escribe aquí el dato a enviar");
            //return 0; 3. El método es void así que no debe retornar nada
        }
        
        public void conectar(Computadora c){
            this.peer = c;
            c.peer = this;
            System.out.println(nombre + ": Conectado a " + peer.nombre);
        }
        
        public void desconectar(){
            System.out.println(nombre + ": Desconectado de " + peer.nombre);
            peer.peer = null;
            this.peer = null;
        }
        
        public void apagar(){
            System.out.println("Cerrando sesión...");
            // 7. El ciclo for debe ser desde 0 hasta 10
            for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
                memoria[i] = null;
            }
            System.out.println(nombre + ": Windows se está cerrando");
            memoria[0] = null;
        }
        
        // 5. El método no debe ser static
        public  void aumentarDiscoDuro(){
            discoDuro = 1000;
        }
        
        public static void main(String[] args){
            Computadora laptop = new Computadora("Laptop");
            laptop.encender();
            laptop.ejecutar("Windows Live Messenger", 1);
            
            Computadora tablet = new Computadora("Tablet");
            tablet.encender();
            tablet.ejecutar("Windows Live Messenger", 1);
            
            laptop.conectar(tablet);    
            laptop.enviarDatos();
            laptop.desconectar();
            
            tablet.apagar();
            laptop.apagar();
        }
    }
```